# Ubuntu Login Password

Tags: 12.04

I have just installed Ubuntu Linux 12.04 and it asks for a password initially, what is the password I need to use? I tried "root" and "toor" as in Backtrack but this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

While installing the system, installer program must ask you for a username and password. This user have full sudo permissions.
Ubuntu block root user by default.

You can login using that username and password and use sudo to run commands as root.